# RecyclerView "No Results" TextView findViewById always returns null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `TextView` in it's place as well for when no results are found.

This `TextView` when calling `root.findViewById` always returns null, I have tried re-cleaning the project, building the project over again. Nothing has helped.

Here are my imports:

```
     import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.HandlerThread;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.mypackage.commoncode.R;
```

Here is the code for the `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mail, container, false);
    //
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final Context context = root.getContext();

    mEmptyView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // set list
    float ht = BitmapUtils.convertDpToPixel(8, context);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    mListView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mListView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mListView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(Float.valueOf(ht).intValue()));

    mListAdapter = new InboxListAdapter(context);
    mListAdapter.setOnInboxClickListener(this);
    mListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

    if (mBackground == null) {
        mBackground = new HandlerThread("background", android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        mBackground.start();
        mBackgroundCallback = new BackgroundCallback(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mCurrentKid);
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackground.getLooper(), mBackgroundCallback);
    }

    final Handler displayHandler = new Handler(new HandlerCallback(this));
    mBackgroundCallback.setDisplayHandler(displayHandler);
    //
    retrieveInboxList(context);

    return root;
}
```

Here is the `XML` for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:text="@string/No_Results_found" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Any ideas as to why the `empty_view` `TextView` is always null?

Logcat error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

at this line:

```
mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: first of all change your @id/spinner to @+id/spinner

Comment: Yea, same error. I will add the null error.

Comment: Appart from the spinner stuff, it looks normal. Can you post your exception?

Comment: Yep just did @droidpl

Comment: And you are fully sure your xml posted is R.layout.fragment_mail? Keep in mind not to have different versions of the same xml for different resolutions

Comment: @droidpl seems another worker added a second layout I had not seen. That was the layout being referred to. Thanks guys sorry for the mess up.

Comment: I have added the answer so you can accept it

Comment: @droidpl yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view xml referenced does not have the view with the id your are trying to retrieve. Make sure the xml posted is the correct one or that you have another xml for this resolution that maybe is not containing the view.